# Nginx DataPower 2 way TLS

Tags: ssl, nginx, ibm-datapower

I have Nginx which proxy request from client to IBM DataPower with mutual TLS.

I have an error when message is sent from Nginx to IBM DP:
sll server (SERVER) ssl peer did not send a certificate during the handshake datapower

Cut from my Nginx config

```
location ~ path {
    proxy_pass https://HOST:PORT; # DataPower
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /opt/nginx/ssl/tr/ca-chain.cert.pem;
    proxy_ssl_certificate       /opt/nginx/ssl/client/client-nginx_cert.pem;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key   /opt/nginx/ssl/client/client-nginx_key.pem;
    proxy_http_version          1.1;
    proxy_ssl_server_name       on;
    proxy_ssl_name                 HOST;
    proxy_set_header Host HOST;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
}
```

Message goes from client directly to IBM DP without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;`